# iOS: Hindi language localization not working unless region is set to India

Tags: ios, xcode, localizable.strings

I have an app that is made in different languages using localization:

[image: Localized strings]

The problem that I have, is that the user also needs to have the region of his phone set to India. If the user's phone is in Hindi but is located in the United States, it will use the default English strings.

[image: Region]

How can I use the Hindi strings even if the region is in a different country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added your localization, you chose "Hindi (India)." You wanted to just select "Hindi" which is unconstrained:

[image]

It's probably easiest to fix this by adding a "hi" localization, copying your strings to it, and then deleting the "hi-IN" localization.

Comment: That worked thanks! For the people that are having a similar problem, just remember that a lot of things are localized. Strings, Assets, .plist etc.. Make sure you do it for all of them.